# How can i dynamically change the background image of a QPushButton in Qt?

Tags: qt, qwidget, qpushbutton

I have a QWidget containing a `QPushButton` and I want to change the image in it without redrawing the whole window.

I tried:

```
ui->btnIcon->setProperty("highlighted", bIcon);
style()->polish(ui->btnIcon);
```

and in .qss file:

```
QPushButton#btnIcon[highlighted=true]{
background-image: url(:/gui/res/Icon1.png);
}

QPushButton#btnIcon[highlighted=false]{
background-image: url(:/gui/res/Icon2.png);
}
```

It works, but I have to wait a while for the change to take place and I also change the text in `QLabel` and that change takes place instantly. Any opinions?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change background using stylesheets:

```
ui.yourButton->setStyleSheet("QPushButton{ background-image: url('blabla.jpg')}");
```

It is immediate.

this is my code and it does the job:

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget),
    isOn_(true)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->pushButton->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-image: url(':blabla1.png')}");
    QObject::connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(changeBack()));
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Widget::changeBack(){

    if(isOn_)
    {
        ui->pushButton->setStyleSheet(" QPushButton {background-image: url(':blabla.gif')}");
    } else {
        ui->pushButton->setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background-image: url(':blabla1.png')}");
    }
    isOn_ = !isOn_;
}
```

check if syntax of your CSS is correct. or the path to your resources is correct..